# Nokia Map Tiles REST API

Tags: here-api

I have an account for Nokia Maps API but am wondering what URL I should use to request tiles through the API correctly? I am using the Leaflet maps API and my URL string looks like this:

http://3.maptile.lbs.ovi.com/maptiler/v2/maptile/newest/normal.day/{z}/{x}/{y}/256/png8?app_id=XXX&token=XXX

It works, but I don't believe I am using the API correctly - I just stole the first part of the URL (http://3.maptile.lbs.ovi.com/maptiler/v2/maptile/newest/normal.day) from the Network tab of dev tools when I checked out Nokia maps in my browser.

In the documentation it tells me I can request based on lat, long and zoom, but not based on X and Y.

Is anybody familiar with Nokia Maps API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the original question I'm guessing you have acquired credentials for the **Map Image API**: http://developer.here.net/docs/map_image/index.html There are a series of interactive examples available, which explain how to get back a static map image using latitude and longitude such as this one here: http://developer.here.net/apiexplorer/examples/api-for-rest/getting-started/basic-map-wh.html All the urls for the Map image API start with  http://m.nok.it

Using URLs for the map tiles from the http://here.com website isn't the same service, it isn't an official API (hence the reason it is undocumented) and the URLs could be changed without notice.

**Updated**

HERE now offers **three** web-based Maps APIs, and since  last year a TMS (*Tile Map Service*) a.k.a. **Map Tile API**, which is what I think you are after is now publicly available.

As noted by *Luciano Issoe*, the **correct URLs** for the **Map Tile API** are now publically documented see: https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/enterprise-map-tile

Alternatively, if you want to use an interactive map service with Nokia's mapping data, your best bet would be to use the **Maps API for Javascript** described here:
http://developer.here.net/docs/maps_js/index.html

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it´s a documented service now: https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/enterprise-map-tile

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve a map covering a specific area using the Map Image API, add two points of interest to the map for the top right and bottom left corner and then use the nomrk to make the POIs invisible:

```
http://m.nok.it/?w=512&poi=52.6764,13.7636,52.351,13.0185&nomrk
```